# How do I refer to data in a column under this month?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

In the below screenshot, I'm trying to get B42 to show the value of whichever cell on row 40 is under the current month's column:

[image: Formula returns N/A]

As the dates are automatically generated using a transpose(arryaformula) function, each month is actually written as `DD/MM/YYYY`. However, I've formatted it so only the `M` and `Y` show.

The formula in the bar was lifted from another answer on here but, understandably, it can't find today's date as each column name is actually the first of each month.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome. The formula in the formula bar isn't easily viewable, please add it as text to the question.

Comment: Formula is:           =index(C40:40,match(TODAY(),C$33:$33,0))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(40, MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1), C33:33, 0)+2))
```

[image: 0]